# Native WCF client for Windows XP

Tags: wcf, visual-c++

I have created program using MSVC++ that besides it's main task calls WCF server functions. Under `Windows 7` and `Windows 8` everything works fine and I got several problems with `Windows XP`:

1. On some machines I have error that `webservice.dll` is missing and program doesn't starts. Why some Windows XP installations contain `webservice.dll` while others - not? How to install required dll?
2. On `Win XP` computers that has `webservice.dll` sometimes programm just crashes without any reporting. After recompiling program without WCF client code program runs fine. What might be starting point to look for the problem?

Comment: webservice.dll is not mine - it is from Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

[*Windows Web Services API (WWSAPI) is an operating-system component of Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 or later versions of Microsoft Windows.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430435(VS.85).aspx)

On Windows XP you need to package it with your app. The reason it works on some boxes is probably caused by one other installed application that uses that the WWSAPI as well.

> The final version of the Windows Web Services API for Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008 is now available
>
> In contrast to the past pre-released version of this API, this final version release can be used in production code and redistributed with the final versions of the product. Because of this, the final version is only available to companies who agree to terms of Windows Master Redistribution License Agreement (MRLA). To acquire the redistributable installers for this release and a copy of the Windows MRLA for review, please email a formal request.

Partially copied and adapted from [Windows Core Networking blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2009/10/09/final-version-of-windows-web-services-api-for-windows-xp-vista-server-2003-and-server-2008-is-now-available.aspx), from [Ari Pernick](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/ari%20pernick%20[msft]/), dated Oct 9th, 2009.

Comment: We don't have MIRLA agreement. That means I have no possibility to get WWSAPI what will include webservice.dll ? Maybe it is possible to download it from somewhere else just for experimental purposes? But why my code crashes when it uses one other installed application WWSAPI ? This might be fault that my application is not installed with its WWSAPI?

Comment: You didn't provide any details about the crashes you experience, do you really expect a reasonable answer?